# Encountering Errors with bookworm-security Package During 'apt-get update'

Tags: linux, debian, updates, apt

i couldn't post this on stack overflow since it said it was spam so here it goes

Description: When executing sudo apt-get update, I'm encountering errors related to the 'bookworm-security' repository. The output of the command includes the following error message.

```
domin@fbi:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease
Hit:2 https://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease                                                                                             
Ign:3 https://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-security InRelease                                                                                    
Hit:4 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease
Get:5 https://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease [52.1 kB]
Hit:6 https://repo.steampowered.com/steam stable InRelease
Err:7 https://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 146.75.118.132 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code/dists/stable/InRelease: The key(s) in the keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/key.gpg are ignored as the file has an unsupported filetype.
W: https://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bookworm/InRelease: The key(s) in the keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/key.gpg are ignored as the file has an unsupported filetype.
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
W: https://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bookworm-updates/InRelease: The key(s) in the keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/key.gpg are ignored as the file has an unsupported filetype.
domin@fbi:~$
```

Problem: The output displays a 404 error specifically related to the 'bookworm-security' repository, indicating the absence of a Release file. Consequently, updating from this repository is disabled due to security concerns.

Request: I seek guidance on resolving this issue with the 'bookworm-security' repository during the 'apt-get update' process. Any insights or steps to rectify this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you have wrong URL for bookworm-security. The correct one is `https://security.debian.org/debian-security`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Debian 12 (Bookworm) has the following defaults repositories :

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm main non-free-firmware
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm main non-free-firmware

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ bookworm-security main non-free-firmware
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ bookworm-security main non-free-firmware

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates main non-free-firmware
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates main non-free-firmware
```

[Reference here](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList)

@Mateuz is right, you have an issue with `bookworm-security`.

You can modify your source file here : `/etc/apt/source.list` (with sudo or as root).